# Data being lost when updating database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model with 2 values (+ PK) -

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string ImageDescription { get; set; }
public byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

But when the user updates the ImageDescription field the image gets deleted from the database.
I'm using the automatically generated controller for editing.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,ImageDescription")] Gallery gallery)
        {
            if (id != gallery.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(gallery);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!GalleryExists(gallery.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(gallery);
        }
```

Comment: Post your update code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have Image in Bind, only ImageDescription, this is why you can't save it.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,ImageDescription")] Gallery gallery)
```

if you don't want to save the new image and want to leave the previous one, you have use this code

```
var existedGallery=_context.Set<Gallery>().FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Id==gallery.Id);

if(existedGallery!=null)
{
existedGallery.ImageDescription=gallery.ImageDescription;
_context.Entry(existedGallery).Property(i => i.ImageDescription).IsModified = true;
var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying better- i don't intend for users to change the image, but just the description. However, when they edit the description the image gets deleted from the database

Comment: @aloneintallinn Yes, it will be deleted the way you are making update

Comment: I've tried something similiar but it gives me the same issue as with your code: "The instance of entity type 'Gallery' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked."

Comment: @aloneintallinn  you don' t need to try anything similar. Just use this code as it is. It never fails.